# Mount shares on a mac from batch files using net use

Tags: bash, scripting, batch-file

I am in a mixed env and have been tasked with mounting shares for mac users by using their already created batch scripts for their windows login.

I have two main problems.

1. Trying to read from the NETLOGON share in a script on a mac
2. Trying to convert the net use commands in those scripts to something that a mac can use.

I've spent most of time working on the part that will convert the whole net use command into something usable for a mac.

I started with:

```
IFS='
'

arr=($(grep '\\' /Users/tjguidry/Desktop/tjguidry.bat | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"))
```

with the expected array being something like this (based on a file I already have):

```
net use n: \\domain\dfs1\share1 /persistent:no
net use r: \\domain\dfs1\share2 /persistent:no
rem net use o: \\domain\dfs1\share3 /persistent:no
rem net use p: "\\domain\dfs1\share4" /persistent:no
```

the grep command does what its supposed to do alone in terminal
But when I output the array, the first slash in \domain gets cut off and for some shares that start with the letter "a" (ie \domain\dfs1\admin) it cuts off the "\a" in the output.
So instead I get:

```
net use n: \domain\dfs1\share1 /persistent:no
net use r: \domain\dfs1\share2 /persistent:no
rem net use o: \domain\dfs1hare3 /persistent:no
rem net use p: "\domain\dfs1hare4" /persistent:no
```

I also can't seem to cut on the "\\" to try and get rid of the first put of the string no matter how I try to escape the slashes.

Ideally I'd like to transform the output to something like this smb://domain/dfs1/share1 for the mac to be able to mount it.

Comment: I'd suggest to place the share/server info in a plain txt file with as little syntax as possible in that file. Then have a separate script for each platform that parses that file. Having Bash parse a windows script seems like a kludge, and it creates a dependency on those windows scripts.

Comment: We already have a huge dependency on them as is. Besides, I was given this as a project requirement, and sadly, I'm not allowed to change those since I'm not "management".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to process the file input correctly:

```
IFS='
'
arr=($(grep '\\' /Users/tjguidry/Desktop/tjguidry.bat | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed s:\"::g | sed s:\\\\:\/:g | sed 's|/persistent:no||g' | sed 's|net use [a-z]: ||g') )
```